# Share .dart-files between test/ and example/

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently writing a dart package. I have a file **data_model.dart** which I included in *test/test.dart* to perform tests based on that file. Now I also want to include it into *example/lib/main.dart* to use it for my example code. Where should I put my file to not violate any package layout conventions and can use it from both *test/* and *example/* at the same time?

Comment: What about extracting that file in a package?

Comment: @RémiRousselet is there a way to embed a package into a package? or do you mean creating an entirely new package?